# How can I add a Custom Payload to an Intent with Dialogflow's Java Client?

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

I was able to create an Intent in Dialogflow following this example:

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/manage-intents#create_intent

That worked just fine, adding plain text responses to that Intent. However, my Dialogflow Agent is using both text responses and a Custom Payload. I can't find any documentation explaining how to do this, so I tried playing around with the code.

I was able to get an empty Custom Payload to show by doing this:

```
Builder messageBuilder = Message.newBuilder();
messageBuilder.setText(Text.newBuilder().addAllText(messageTexts).build());
messageBuilder.setPayload(Struct.newBuilder().build());
```

However, this results in JUST the Custom Payload, not the Text responses. I have two questions:

1. How can I add some String content to the Custom Payload?
2. How can I have both Text responses and Custom Payload at the same time?

Comment: I can answer my own second question, I feel kinda dumb. I should use two different MessageBuilders, one for the text responses and one for the Custom Payload, and then create the Intent passing both. However, I still can't figure out how to add text to the Custom Payload

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Struct.newBuilder().putFields(field).build());`
where field is a Value that you can build as below :

```
Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(yourStringValue).build();
```